# Caps lock is always enable in win 10 startup

Tags: windows-10

Caps Lock is always enabled after Windows 10 starts up. I try to edit Registry [as suggest in the web](http://winaero.com/blog/enable-numlock-logon-screen-windows-10/) to set initial keyboard value to 0. But every time I restart the computer, the Caps Lock is on and the initial keyboard value in Registry goes back to 2 again.

**I have switched Caps Lock with the left Control using `keytweak`. After I switch back, the problem is gone. But this doesn't make any sense, or why does this happen?**

Here are the THREE question:

1. Why the initial value of `"InitialKeyboardIndicators"` in Registry is always set to 2 after I have changed it to 0.
2. How can I have Caps Lock turned off when the computer boots, at the same time keep Caps Lock switching with the left Control?
3. Why does this happen? Under the hood, what is the relation between the key in a keyboard with the computer inside?

[image: This is the picture from keytweak]

Comment: Some computers have a setting in the BIOS for CAPS lock on startup.  Did you check this?

Comment: 2 does not mean Caps Lock on. It means Num Lock on. Caps Lock on is 1. Of course, that's for Windows 7. Did you try setting the value to 80000000?

Comment: On the closer inspection of the article to which you linked, the article suggests 2147483650 for Windows 10. Did you try that?

Comment: @FleetCommand I have try them all. The issue is every time I restart the value back to 2again, no matter what number I have set.

Comment: @JoelAZ My computer is Acer, and I press F2 into the BIOS, but found none setting related to the capslock(or keyboard).

Comment: @FleetCommand thanks for your edit. It seem my edit has make the tag that show you have edited disappear.

Comment: @EvanL00 It was a shot in the dark.  Not all computers have it but I thought it was worth suggesting.  Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking under `HKU\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard`? Aren't you by accident looking under `HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard`?

Comment: @FleetCommand I have set the two places to 0 or 8000000 but  it still doesn't work, maybe involved keytweak see my bold sentence in the question